# How can i set field mandatory to false using javascript

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am new to **netsuite** scripting using **javascript**. I like to ask, how can I set field mandatory to false using javascript.

Hope that someone can help me.

Comment: I try to use the API setMandatory(mandatory) but it doesnt work or i dont know how to use it. Appreciate the help. Thank you

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: var field = nlapiGetField('fieldname');
            field.setMandatory(false);

Answer (score 2):

### Note :

If you use `nlapiGetField(fieldname)` in a client script to return a `nlobjField` object, the object returned is *`read-only`*. This means that you can use `nlobjField` getter methods on the object, however, you cannot use `nlobjField` setter methods to set field properties.

However you can use
`nlapiSubmitRecord(item_obj, true, true);` to ignore mandatory fields on a record.
For more details check out the included parameters in the method.
`nlapiSubmitRecord(record, doSourcing, ignoreMandatoryFields);`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74575/discussion-on-answer-by-rockstar-how-can-i-set-field-mandatory-to-false-using-ja).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct methods, but `setMandatory` is not supported in a client script. You can instead try using the exact same code in a User Event, Before Load event handler.

Contrary to the documentation, the `nlobjField` returned by `nlapiGetField` is *not* read-only. Some of the setter methods still work (e.g. `setDisplayType`) on the client side. You can experiment with which ones do and do not work, but `setMandatory` is confirmed as not supported on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me based on the input from @erictgrubaugh and @user3627301

```
function fieldChanged(type,name){   
    var metodPayment=nlapiGetFieldText('field_id_to_check');
    if ((name == 'field_id_to_monitor_for_change') && (metodPayment=='Financing')) {            
        var field1 = nlapiGetField('field_id_to_be_disabled'); 
        field1.setDisplayType('disabled');
    }               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using SS2.0 on a client script you can make it mandatory with this code:

```
var newSupervisorField = context.currentRecord.getField('custrecord_new_supervisor');
newSupervisorField.isMandatory = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set mandatory using SuiteScript 2.0 though although it does not works in 1.0.

Below, is an example snippet using client script on customer record

```
var currentRecord;require(['N/currentRecord'], (currentRecord) => {
  var field = currentRecord.get().getField('comments');
  field.isMandatory = true;
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe my answer was already late but for others that came across this post, this is how I do it via client script.

```
nlapiSetFieldMandatory('yourFieldId', true);
```

This was already tested because I am using this often. Though some says you cannot set fields to mandatory via client but you can. I did not find any docs about this on netsuite docs though.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. It will give the field the red asterisk indicating that it is mandatory, but it does not actually make it mandatory. You would have to interrupted the saveRecord function, check that the field has a value, display an alert (if appropriate) and return the appropriate value to stop the save if it's empty.