# How to make sublist field mandatory?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript1.0

This is my pageInit function

```
function poTransPageInit(type) {
    //   alert('page init');
    var field= nlapiGetLineItemField('item', 'field');
    field.isMandatory = true;
}
```

what I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that the isMandatory method is not available in Client Scripts.  As a work around you could get the field's value and check the length.

```
function validateLine(type){
  if(type == 'sublistInternalID'){ //sublistInternalID = sublist internal id, i.e. 'item'
    //get the sublist field value of mandatory column
    var name = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('line', 'fieldId'); //line = line #, fieldId = internal id of field
    //if value length is greater than 0, then there is a value
    if(name.length > 0){
      return true;
    } else {
      alert('Please enter a value for Name field');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`field.isMandatory` is SuiteScript 2.0.  In SuiteScript 1.0, you would use `field.setMandatory(true)`, but [apparently that function is not available in client scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29474558/675137).

You could try moving this logic to a User Event script.