# How to set a Field Mandatory with a script

Tags: workflow, suitescript2.0

If an item is picked in the sublist, I need to make a field mandatory in a sales order form.
How can I do it, I was informed that with a Workflow I can't.

So I'll need to use suite script, how is the best approach to do it?
Can you tell me how to as well?

Thank you.

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466832/how-can-i-set-field-mandatory-to-false-using-javascript